# Can I create a unit test in ANgular that makes real http calls without mocking them?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I have a monolite app in Angular and i'm still trying to understand everything related to unit testing, i need to test some services, i often read online that when it comes to test a service i have to mock the http calls, like get, post, ecc... i can't understand why, is there a way to test it without mocking?
i've also read that i could use a spy, but i don't understand how should i use it...
I just need to test if some http calls returns the values that i expect, what's the most complete way i can do it?
please explain it to me in the siplest way you can or paste any link related to this specific topic.
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to test without mocking the API, so it won't be a unit test, but rather an integration test.

**Cypress**
If you just want a quick way to check that some http calls return the values that you expect, Cypress might be a good start. See here a tutorial on how to get started: https://circleci.com/blog/api-testing-with-cypress/.
Basically, you just do a cy.request, then write your assertions about the data you expect.

**Postman**
This might also be useful in your case: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/

**Jasmine**
You can do real requests with Jasmine too:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule // <-- simply provide the actual HttpModule here
      ]
    });

  });

  it('should do real requests', async(inject([Http], (http) => {
    http.get('your url').subscribe(res => {
      expect(res.json()).toBe(...);
    });
  })));
```

Comment: so there is no way to check that some http calls return the values that I expect with jasmine? (I have to use only karma and jasmine)

Comment: Yes, Jasmine works too. I've updated my answer with a code sample.